# trouble with optimx() ("Cannot evaluate function at initial parameters")

Tags: r

I would like to maximize a function of x1, x2, and x3 as follows

```
f <- function(x) x[1]*14.1638 + x[2]*4.2062 + 
   x[3]*0.6700 - x[1]*x[2]*2.2175 + x[1]*x[3]*2.8800 + 
   x[2]*x[3]*2.0450 + x[1]*x[1]*9.9863 - 
   x[2]*x[2]*12.6738 - x[3]*x[3]*10.9062 + 36.4100

params <- c(1,1,1)

r <- optimx(params, f,gr=NULL, hess=NULL,  lower=-1, upper=1, 
    method=c("Nelder-Mead", "L-BFGS-B"), itnmax=c(50), 
    maximize=TRUE )

r$convergence == 0

r$par
```

But I am getting the warning message

> Error in optimx.check(par, optcfg$ufn, optcfg$ugr, optcfg$uhess, lower,  : 
>         Cannot evaluate function at initial parameters

I am pretty sure I am missing something basic in function parameters but I am not able to figure out what.

Answer (score 2):

It took some digging to figure it out (`debug(optimx:::optim.check))`), but it looks like this is a confusing error message that occurs because you specified `maximize=TRUE` rather than `control=list(maximize=TRUE)` (`optimx` tried to pass `maximize=TRUE` through to your function as an additional argument, which failed).

Try:

```
r <- optimx(params, f,gr=NULL, hess=NULL,  lower=-1, upper=1, 
    method=c("Nelder-Mead", "L-BFGS-B"), itnmax=c(50), 
    control=list(maximize=TRUE ))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! 
I actually managed to solve this problem by using the oprim() function where I defined my f function as a function of x1,x2,x3 then defined another function g as a function of plain f (because the optim only accepts one-input fn) and then I used the memory-limited B method to maximize my function in the range required.